# Passing function invocation as a parameter

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object with functions as properties:

```
var o = {
   "f1":function(){alert('invoke one');},
   "f2":function(){alert('invoke two');},
   "f3":function(){alert('invoke three');}
};
```

I am planning to use _.each of http://underscorejs.org/ to invoke them.
So, my invocation will look like

```
_.each(o, function(f){f();});
```

what irritates is the second parameter for _.each. If there is a such function "invoke", I could just call `_.each(o,invoke);`

I know that defining invoke is fairly easy:

```
function invoke (f){f();}
```

but I just want to know if there is anything built-in that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native function that does this. You could have a bit fun with [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
var invoke = Function.prototype.call.bind(Function.prototype.call)
```

but declaring `invoke` like you did is much simpler.

With Underscore.js, you can however use the [`invoke` method](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke):

```
_.invoke(o, Function.prototype.call);
_.invoke(o, "call");
_.invoke(o, Function.prototype.apply, []);
_.invoke(o, "apply", []);
```

Comment: I ended up with _.invoke(_.values(o), "call"); seems _.invoke assumes the first parameter to be an array.

Comment: Hm, the docs say it works on any collections, including objects. I've tested your object and it worked. Maybe you need a different Underscore version?