# Is there any JavaScript/Underscore/jQuery shortcut for function(i,x) { x(); }?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, callback, underscore.js

I have a array of listener functions, like:

```
var tab = [ function() {console.log(1);} , function(){console.log(2);} ]
```

And I can notify all my listeners without writing a loop, by:

```
$.each( tab , function(i,x) { x(); } );
```

Eventually, I can extract my function to common place:

```
$.each( tab , myLib.call );
```

But is there any shortcut for doing that array call in JS / jQuery / underscore?

Comment: `tab.forEach(function (i) { i() })`?

Comment: @epascarello JS is functional language and I'm trying to get pros of that characteristic, not write everytinhg imperative way. lante of course your code is shorter but I am afraid of compatibility. OlimSaidov you really think that "notify all listeners" is rare case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend [Underscore's `invoke`](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke):

```
_.invoke(tab, Function.prototype.call);
```

See also [Passing function invocation as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26979538/1048572).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Function.prototype.call`, like this

```
$.each(tab, Function.prototype.call);
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/nemocu/1/edit?html,js,output)